# How to navigate child Entity Framework objects in generic method?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, generics

I have a generic method in my repository which updates a property common to all the objects in my edmx model:

```
    private void SetUpdateParams(TEntity entity)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("CommonProperty");

        prop.SetValue(entity, "Some Value", null);
    }
```

This property is called by the add, update and delete methods.  Example:

```
    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        SetUpdateParams(entity);
        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
        txDB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This all works fabulously well, until I try to include children in a cascade delete scenario. Since the sprocs I have to use require that this certain property is set, I must now recurse through the relationships and set this property on any loaded children in the ObjectSet.  Problem is I can't seem to figure out any way to do that.  Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the easiest solution and can be a tad tedious, but I implemented what you're needing in a project of mine by spanning the object graph, updating the property as I found it, and keeping track of what I've visited.  It gave great flashbacks to undergrad computer science classes.  =)

Essentially, take your object, get its properties, and push them on a stack.  For each property on the stack, test if it's the property you're looking for.  Handle if match, ignore if simple data type, add to stack if complex object.

A couple of things that aided me in my implementation:

- Create an interface containing the property you're looking for and make all classes that have the property implement it.  It makes it easier to interrogate your classes with reflection.
- Try to be smart with the types of complex properties you throw on the stack to be traversed.  I used an interface that designates that this complex type may have a property that needs to be updated.
- Use something (I used a HashSet) to mark objects you've seen and help prevent circular reference traversals.
- I have this functionality as part of a BaseContext's (inheriting EF's `ObjectContext`) custom Save() method.  I call this fixup and then call `base.SaveChanges()`.

Like I said, not an easy, straightforward question, but my code handles deep object graphs and updates multiple property instances.  If interested, I can follow-up with some pseudo code.

---

**EDIT/UPDATE**

As the code shows, I'm interested in updating current UserName and DateTime values for any number of objects that may appear in the graph.

**Notes:**

- Interface `IInsertedInfo` contains the properties that we need to update.  So if an object implements `IInsertedInfo`, we know to update its properties.
- An object that implements `IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime` is one that has, somewhere in its graph, an object that implements `IInsertedInfo`.
- This is done in context of a save with EF.  I'm interrogating the `ObjectStateManager` for objects that need to be saved/updated.

I don't claim this to be the most succinct solution, but it works fine for me.  Additionally, checks for `IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime` and other filters (some omitted for clarity's sake) are used solely to keep the search space manageable and to avoid spanning .NET objects, non-class types, etc.

```
private void HandleInsertedUserNames(string userName)
{
    // grab any entity that requires a current user value
    var requiresUser = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified)
                                              .Where(ose => ose.Entity is IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime
                                                            || ose.Entity is IInsertedInfo)
                                              .Select(ose => ose.Entity);

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    object current;
    var seen = new HashSet<object>();
    var stack = new Stack<object>();
    // for each entity requiring a current user value...
    foreach (var obj in requiresUser)
    {
        // traverse its object graph and update any objects that implement IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime
        stack.Push(obj);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            current = stack.Pop();
            if (current != null && !seen.Contains(current))
            {
                // mark object as seen
                seen.Add(current);
                // if object implements IInsertedInfo, then set its property
                if (current is IInsertedInfo)
                {
                    (current as IInsertedInfo).UserName = userName;
                    (current as IInsertedInfo).DateTime = now;
                    // we can continue on to the next object in the stack if we've hit an IInsertedInfo
                    continue;
                }

    // REMOVED FILTERING TESTS I USED TO REDUCE SEARCH SPACE (e.g.: is modified?)

                if (current is IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime)
                {
                    // push any instance, public properties and push them to the stack
                    current.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    // HERE YOU CAN FILTER THE PROPERTY COLLECTION VIA WHERE CLAUSES (e.g.: only certain namespace, type, etc)
                           // select the actual value of the property
                           .Select(type => type.GetValue(current, null))
                           // further filter -- only values NOT already in the requiresUser
                           // list and those that implement IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime or IInsertedInfo
                           .Where(value => !requiresUser.Contains(value)
                                           && (value is IRequiresCurrentUserDateTime
                                               || value is IInsertedInfo))
                           .ToList().ForEach(stack.push);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hrm - that's far more complex than I thought it would be.  Wondering if the cost to value ratio is too high...but I would love to see some pseudo code, if you don't mind?  Thanks a lot for the direction as well...I never would have thought of using an interface to make this work!